# E/PDFCreatorioException:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/PDF/form.pdf (No such file or directory)

Tags: android

I want to create a pdf file.I tried several times with this code and got same exception .i dont know what wrong i did.please help

MANIFEST:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

MY CODE:

```
  public void createPdf(String text) {

    Document doc = new Document();

    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";

        File dir = new File(path);
        if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        Log.d("createPdf", "PDF Path: " + path);

        File file = new File(dir, "form.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);
        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(text);

        p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);

        doc.add(p1);

    } catch (DocumentException de) {
        Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
    }
    finally {
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code with error log please. It will be helpful for views.

Comment: i have already posted my code.Sorry actually there was no error but i got same exception   E/PDFCreatorioException:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/PDF/form.pdf (No such file or directory)

Comment: try dir.mkdir();

Comment: try this - > String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PDF/";

Comment: I tried. But got same result

Comment: make sure you have proper permission.

Comment: i made this permission in manifest file      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: is it not sufficient?

Comment: Yes that means your app needs the permission. But that doesn't mean your app allowed that permission.

Comment: how to confirm?